# Html.Dropdownlist selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, selected

I am using dropdownlist in asp.net mvc.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityList",new SelectList(
Model.Select(x => new { Value = x.CityID, Text = x.Name, Selected = 1 }), "Value", "Text", "Selected"), "Choose",
new { @id = "CityListId" })
```

I have cities list.There is a data called "New York" it is Id is 1.

When i give **1 id for selected** , i must see New york.However there is no appearing data.

where i miss exactly ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In your Controller :

```
ViewBag.CityList= new SelectList(db.Model.where(x=>x.CityID == 1),"CityID","Name");
```

In your View :

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityList",null,--Select One--,new { @id = "CityListId" })
```